# Javascript function to check two date ranges using Date.UTC works in all browsers but Firefox

Tags: javascript, validation

Folks,

I'll preface this with I don't have much Javascript experience.  I was trying to do some client side checking on form submit to prevent a user from running a report if they put in a date range greater than a year, but otherwise let them run it.  Here is the function

```
function revDays() {

var _MS_PER_Day=24*60*60*1000;

var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('FROM').value);
var sy = startDate.getUTCFullYear(); 
var sm = startDate.getUTCMonth();
var sd = startDate.getUTCDate();

var endDate = new Date(document.getElementById('TO').value);
var ey = endDate.getUTCFullYear(); 
var em = endDate.getUTCMonth();
var ed = endDate.getUTCDate();

var utc1 = Date.UTC(sy, sm, sd);
var utc2 = Date.UTC(ey, em, ed);  

//alert("utc1 variable is " + utc1);
//alert("utc2 variable is " + utc2);

var dayDiff = Math.floor(utc2 - utc1);

//alert("dayDiff var is " + dayDiff);

var diff =  Math.floor((utc2 - utc1)/_MS_PER_Day);

//alert("diff var is " + diff);

 if (diff > 365) {
  alert("This report cannot be run for more than 365 days at a time.  Please adjust your date range and try again");
  return false;
  }
 else {
    return true;
    }
};
```

I call this function on form submit

```
<form name="Report" method="post" action="report.php" target="_blank" onsubmit="return revDays(this)">
```

This works as expected in Chrome, IE and Safari, however Firefox returns `NaN` on any of the vars once you start adding in the Date.UTC functions.  You can see my commented out alerts where I compared in other browsers that Date.UTC is properly converting the string into a date object in MS, however FireFox simply returns `NaN` despite their documentation stating they support Date.UTC

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Can anyone point me in the right direction to what I'm missing?  The similar questions I found on SO were about comparing two dates, and in this case I need to get the number of days between two values, and not a simple boolean is equal to check.

Comment: What are the values of these elements "FROM" and "TO"?

Comment: Your issue is here: `new Date(document.getElementById('FROM').value);` Do not parse strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) since it's largely implementation dependent (as you've discovered). Use a small parsing function (3 or 4 lines) if you only have to support one format, or a library otherwise.

Comment: PPS Creating a Date, then using it's UTC values with Date.UTC simply creates a time value for an identical instant in time (i.e. it's pointless). ;-)

Comment: Nan is the return value of an invalid date object: indicating Firefox is treating the form input field content as an invalid input string. See if you can extract date fields (your own parsing as commented by @RobG) to construct the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue almost certainly comes from:

```
new Date(document.getElementById('FROM').value);
```

which infers parsing of a string using the Date constructor. That is never a good idea, you should always explicitly advise the parser of the format you're using. The built–in EMCAScript parser doesn't allow that, so it just guesses at the format and maybe gets it right, or not.

So write a small parser for your required format, or use a library that lets you tell it the format. I'll assume that it's D/M/Y just for the sake of it:

Below is a simple parser for D/M/Y format. Now to tell if two dates are more than 1 year apart, you can simply add 1 year to the earlier date and see if it's larger than the later date. If so, it's less than 1 year before. The only trick is 29 Feb plus a year gives 1 March, but that is only going to occur very rarely.

The following example validates the dates, shows messages if the dates are invalid and determines if the dates are more or less than 1 year apart.

```js
// Parse and validate date in format dd/mm/yyyy
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

// Check if d1 is less than or equal to 1 year after d0
function checkRangeLessThanOneYear(d0, d1) {
  return d0.setFullYear(d0.getFullYear() + 1) >= d1;  
}

function checkRange(form) {
  var d0 = parseDMY(form.startDate.value);
  var d1 = parseDMY(form.endDate.value);
  if (isNaN(d0.getTime())) {
    alert('Start date is invalid');
    return;
  }
  if (isNaN(d1.getTime())) {
    alert('End date is invalid');
    return;
  }
  alert(checkRangeLessThanOneYear(d0, d1)? 'All good' : 'Range more than 1 year');
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="checkRange(this); return false;">
  Start date (d/m/y)<input name="startDate"><br>
  End date (d/m/y)<input name="endDate"><br>
  <button>Check Dates</button>
</form>
```